# visualize predict_proba for multiclass classification

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, data-visualization

With `model.predict_proba(X)` I just get a big array with lots of numbers.

I am looking for a way to visualize the probabilities of a classification for all classes (in my case 13). I use a `RandomForestClassifier`.

Any recommendation?

Comment: What is the dimension of your input space?

Comment: It is from several hundreds to up to a couple of thousands for a total of 13 classes.

Comment: IMHO, an approach like @Venkatachalam's won't give a useful visualization, because you need to give some sense of the pattern of outputs -- my first thought would be to do it based on inputs, like my answer below. In your case this requires first doing a dimensionality reduction from d=2000 or whatever to d=2, but this is not hard or unusual to viz high-dim data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heatmaps would be nice way to visualise a 2D matrix. Of-course, if the number of records in your `X` is large, it is hard to visualize everything in a single go. Probably you have to sample records otherwise. Here I'm showing the visuals for first 10 records, labelling the predicted classes if the predicted probability is greater than `0.1`.

Check out this example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000,n_features=40,
                           n_informative=30, n_classes=13,
                           n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=1,
                           random_state=42)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=42)

forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)

pred = forest.predict_proba(X_test)[:10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (20,8))
im = ax.imshow(pred, cmap='Blues')

ax.grid(axis='y')
ax.set_xticklabels([])

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(pred.shape[0]))

plt.ylabel('Records', fontsize='xx-large')
plt.xlabel('Classes', fontsize='xx-large')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, fraction=0.046, pad=0.04) 

for i in range(pred.shape[0]):
    for j in range(13):
        if pred[i, j] >.1:
             ax.text(j, i, j,
                     ha="center", va="center", color="w", fontsize=30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your input space is 2D, or if you use some dimensionality reduction technique to embed it in 2D, you could plot the multiclass decision surface:

```py
# generate toy data
X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=13)

# fit classifier
clf = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier().fit(X, y)

# create decision surface
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-13, 12, 100),
                     np.linspace(-13, 12, 100))
Z = clf.predict(np.array([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).T)
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=y, cmap='Paired')
ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap='Paired', alpha=0.5)
```

[image: decision surface]

Note this is only shading per label (`predict` not `predict_proba`) but you may be able to extend this to shade differently based on the probability.